# "Implementing" base factory method in Java/Groovy lang

Tags: java, groovy

I'm working on a model factory that create business models from test data stores in Katalon Studio. It's been *years* since I seriously touched Java, especially to do any sort of generic programming.

**How I'm trying to do it**

I'll have some `BaseModelFactory`, defined to be:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors

import com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestData

public class BaseModelFactory<T> {
    public static List ModelsFrom(TestData testData) {
    return testData.getAllData()
        .stream()
        .map { row -> this.ModelFromRow(row) }
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
    }

    public static <T> T ModelFrom(TestData testData, int rowNum) {
    return ModelFromRow(testData.getAllData().get(rowNum))
    }

    private static <T> T ModelFromRow(List<Object> row) {
    return null
    }
}
```

and then, whenever we have a data store that we want to create business models from, we simply create a derived factory that implements `ModelsFrom`. For example:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

import com.xxx.models.contract.ContractModel

public class ContractModelFactory extends BaseModelFactory<ContractModel> {

    private static ContractModel ModelFromRow(List<Object> row) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");

    return new ContractModel(
        Integer.parseInt(row[0]),
        row[1],
        dateFormat.parse(row[2]),
        dateFormat.parse(row[3]),
        //...
        )
    }
}
```

**OK, so what's the problem?**

The problem is that, whenever I run a Test Case, with

```
WebUI.verifyNotEqual(
    ContractModelFactory.ModelFrom(findTestData("whatever"), 1),
    null
)
```

, where `"whatever"` points to a non-empty data file, it fails! When I go to debug it, I see that `BaseModelFactory.ModelFromRow` is getting hit, instead of the hiding static method `ContractModelFactory.ModelFromRow` !

How do I fix this?

**DISCLAIMER**: In case you didn't see it in the start of the paragraph, I am doing this in Katalon Studio environment.

Comment: Ill upvote for the weirdness that you see, but I am not sure how someone can answer this. it surely looks like impossible to re-produce for us?

Comment: Repro is straightfoward. This came from working in Katalon Studio. 

- get Katalon Studio 
- create the above `BaseModelFactory`, `ContractModelFactory`
- create some `ContractModel` that has at least the constructor signature `(int, String, Date, Date)`
- create an Excel file with a couple rows of data
- create new Test Data for it in Katalon
- create a test case for it, asserting that `ContractModelFactory.ModelFrom([your test data], 1)` is not null

Comment: Actually you can't override static method -search internet for explanation.

Comment: @daggett I see that. 

What can we do instead?

Comment: for example remove static from `ModelFromRow` and maybe make it abstract in BaseMF.

Comment: It seems like I should make this factory non-static...